# RE: Chida prayer for love and unity

Tags: tefilla, tzibur-community, love

From what source is the Chida's prayer for the unity and love of Israel? It's on p 212-213 of the RCA's Siddur Avodat Halev, but it's unsourced besides saying the Chida wrote it. Halp?

Comment: https://www.tfilah.org/tfilot/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%90%D7%97%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%95%D7%90%D7%94%D7%91%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C/

Comment: What else you looking for? The Chida composed it?

Comment: @Dov I think he's asking where the Chida published it, i.e., how is known that it's from the Chida?

Comment: I think they want to see the original publication of it. He has a sefer with tons of tefillos he wrote. Probably there

Comment: Take a look at the siddur hachida where it seems to have a condensed version of the tefillah here - https://beta.otzar.org/#/book/51012/p/61/t/0.43486613306865011234/fs/zgONDO6kKwYCpEABulzuQgSfSBdgbV6l2cYkFDrtCtIQ/start/0/end/4/c it has a brief introductory line prior which has some sources although I haven't worked them out yet?

Comment: Im looking for where the Chida originally published it